# Pulling songs from iOS music library into an App?

Tags: iphone, ios, html, mobile, mp3

I am developing an HTML5 mobile application that should allow users to upload music directly into the application.

The music **should** be able to be pulled from:

1. Youtube (opens YouTube interface to insert YouTube link)
2. SoundCloud (opens SoundCloud profile to insert link/mp3)
3. Upload from Phone (open iOS music library within phone to select song to upload)

**Question:**
I want to allow the users to pick a song from their iOS native music library and upload it directly into the app as an mp3.

I've read that a possible solution is to copy the raw song data to the App Storage Directory via the AVAssetReader.

Any other good solutions?

Comment: The thing I can say is that I'm **almost** sure that Apple does not allow anyone to upload music from an iDevice without jailbreak. I'm not sure, so if it's wrong, please don't vote down.

Answer (score 1):

Im going to assume then this is a hybrid so the app will be part native. Yes, you can get the raw song data. You can get it in a variety of different file types. You can do whatever you want to it. You want to somehow send it across to a server, and then load it back into your app on the html5 web interface? Sounds crazy but you might be able to do that. You also might have legal issues and get denied from the app store.

Comment: You are right about accessing songs but as far as uploading the same song that has been extracted then no it can't be done due to copy right and sharing laws. Plus one for a good answer though.:)